# CoreData - Adding # of months to a NSDate within a NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

I have an entity in my CoreData model that contains these 2 attributes:

```
startDate (NSDate)
terms (int)
```

I need to grab all the objects where the start plus the terms (which is months) is within the next 30 days.

Here is what I need to do in some pseudo code:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startDate.months + terms) <= %@", date30DaysFromNow];
```

This may not be possible (or I am just being dumb).

I know the alternate solution would be to create a new attribute that creates this date when I import the objects.. but if I can I would rather not have to add another attribute if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a startTime and endTime? instead of startTime and terms. Then you can filter using endTime.

Comment: The real problem is that "startDate + x month" requires calendrical calculations because one month does not have a fixed length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an attribute, which is an NSDate, to your model object. Whenever the date or terms attributes are updated (or on-demand depending on what you use it for ad how often) update this new date to be `startDate.months + terms` (most likely using `NSDateComponents` or `- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds`. Then use this attribute in your predicate.

Comment: So to be clear.. what I want to do in my predicate is not possible and I must create a new attribute. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you can do some things in predicates but you can't add a number of months to a date I'm afraid.

Comment: But you can't use a transient attribute in a (Core Data) predicate, I think.

Comment: @MartinR, good point and entirely correct. Answer edited, thanks.

Comment: Figured I would have to add a new attribute.. I just wanted to make sure before I did. Thanks.